# need to add scrolling bar to sub menu items

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui, angular-ui-bootstrap

How can I add scrolling bar to my Filter sub menu? I have nearly 100 items in that list. Please find the [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/9ofif0MmaqZ11Q6i17hi?p=preview). The following is my sub menu code,

```
<li class="dropdown-submenu"><a href>Filter Sub Menu</a>
    <ul class="dropdown-menu">
        <li ng-repeat="filt in savedFilterList "> <a href> {{filt.filter_name}}</a> </li>
    </ul>
</li>
```

Comment: just use css? when data inside a container will overflow, the scrollbar will appear. If you always want to show it, you can do so too. http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_overflow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's all about css.

You just have to put something like this

```
.dropdown-submenu{
   overflow-y : scroll;
}
```

Or you can also use auto will show you the scroll bar only if needed. But to do so, you have to set a size with it.

Comment: Still the problem is not solved.  Rather it is breaking sub menu appearance too. Please find my updated plunker http://plnkr.co/edit/4fiJyhDXrXY60xvOlw4P?p=preview.

Comment: Yeah my bad, my example wasn't smart. I was brain by the name, it wasn't on the submenu but on the menu. It was `.dropdown-submenu>.dropdown-menu` to be more accurate. I've done it here with the auto scroll : http://plnkr.co/edit/R7AvOcAFAieRebEgzPRf?p=preview